# Have model keep track of input's value attribute - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am making a series of "radio buttons" but are images (meaning only 1 can be chosen per grouping). My problem is that I am new to Angular and I cannot seem to find a way to keep track of the `value` and store that as my `ng-model`.

On a side note, I also am trying to find a simple way to keep images at full opacity when selected, but when you change group selection it un-opacities everything. (click one in group one, then in group 2 will remove the opacity set on group 1's selection), is there a simply angular attribute that will allow me to keep items remain in focus when changing groups.

Here is a **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8146/)**, it just has two groups but you can see the issue in regards to the value not updating, and the images loses opacity when the opposite group is selected.

**HTML** (Angular code just has the variables s1, s2, ect..)

```
<div style="background:white">

            <input value="2" class="pastElos" name="season1" type="image" src="{{images[0].source}}" title="Season1 Bronze" ng-model="s1" style="width:70px; height:75px" />
            <input value="3" class="pastElos" name="season1" type="image" src="{{images[1].source}}" title="Season1 Silver" ng-model="s1" />
            <input value="4" class="pastElos" name="season1" type="image" src="{{images[2].source}}" title="Season1 Gold" ng-model="s1" />
            <input value="5" class="pastElos" name="season1" type="image" src="{{images[3].source}}" title="Season1 Platinum" ng-model="s1" />

<br />
Current Season 1 Value:<span style="color:black">{{s1}}</span>
<hr />

            <input value="6" class="pastElos" name="season2" type="image" src="{{images[0].source}}" title="Season2 Bronze" ng-model="s2" style="width:70px; height:75px" />
            <input value="7" class="pastElos" name="season2" type="image" src="{{images[1].source}}" title="Season2 Silver" ng-model="s2" />
            <input value="8" class="pastElos" name="season2" type="image" src="{{images[2].source}}" title="Season2 Gold" ng-model="s2" />
            <input value="9" class="pastElos" name="season2" type="image" src="{{images[3].source}}" title="Season2 Platinum" ng-model="s2" />

<br />
Current Season 2 Value:<span style="color:black">{{s2}}</span>


        </div>
```

**TLDR ISSUES** **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8146/)**

1. Need to keep track of the value currently selected for each Season. (s1, s2)
2. Need to keep opacity at full when you select items from different groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an input radio and put your image in label you may have the behavior you want

```
<input value="2" id="s1-2" name="season1" type="radio" ng-model="s1" />
<label for="s1-2">
    <img class="pastElos" src="{{images[0].source}}" title="Season1 Bronze"/>
</label>
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8151/)

For IE support on form you may refer to the [following article](http://madebyted.com/blog/using-images-as-labels-inside-forms-in-internet-explorer-11/)
The bug report is [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/809378/using-images-as-labels-inside-forms-in-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: This works perfectly! Is there an easy to way to click an item and unhighlight it if its already highlighted (checked)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:checked` selector on your radio button styles, instead of `:focus`

Also change your input type to `radio` and apply a background image to each button.

Example input:

```
<input value="2" class="pastElos" name="season1" type="radio" title="Season1 Bronze" ng-model="s1" style="background-image: url({{images[0].source}});" />
```

Radio button styles:

```
.pastElos {
    /* ... */
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: none;
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgze8u9m/)</kbd>

Comment: that will not work with inputs I believe, or at least it isn't working in my Fiddle. I am using these "like" checkboxes, they are not actual checkboxes if you note the code.

Comment: My mistake. I will update my answer with a way to style radio buttons to look like what you have.

Comment: Very cool, let me implement it into my app and make sure it works fine :)

Comment: This will only work in Chrome/Safari as expected. It will not do anything in IE, and will still show the radio button borders in Firefox. If you need a cross browser solution, go with @AdlenAfane 's solution.

Comment: IE does not support the `appearance` property, which allows disabling the default browser css of form elements.

Comment: In the future, other browsers may support it, so keep it in mind.

Comment: Okay cool! It seems like Adlen's answer "works" the best, but I kinda wish yours did. Gave ya the upvote but will give him the answer. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Adlen doesn't seem to be responding but I ran into an issue. His solutions works great, but the second I move it into a `form` it breaks (in IE).. Any idea why? Would the CSS he uses to reference it not be reaching it anymore since its in a `form`?